# comparar e remover elemento repetido

Tags: java, array

Eu tenho esse array de objetos, e gostaria de percorrer e remover o autor repetido pelo nome, mas não consigo.

```
public class Pessoa {

    private Autor autor[];
    int cont = 0;

    public Pessoa(Autor autor[]) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Autor[] getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void adiciona(Autor a) {
        this.autor[cont++] = a;
    }


}

public class Autor {

    private String nome;
    public Autor(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Autor))
            return false;
        Autor autor = (Autor) obj;
        return this.nome.equals(autor.nome);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
     return "Meu nome é: " + nome;
    }
}

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pessoa p = new Pessoa(new Autor[3]);

        Autor a1 = new Autor("Leonardo");
        Autor a2 = new Autor("Leonardo");
        Autor a3 = new Autor("Joao");



        p.adiciona(a1);
        p.adiciona(a2);
        p.adiciona(a3);


        Autor autor[] = p.getAutor();

        for(Autor a : autor) {

            if(a !=  null) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Queria remover o nome duplicado, ou deixar null, tem alguma maneira?

```
for(Autor a : autor) {

                if(a !=  null) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Para remover um elemento de uma lista, você deve usar o `iterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma verificação extra na hora de adicionar um item. Caso já exista, simplesmente não adicione:

```
public void adiciona(Autor a) {
    for (Autor b : autor) {
        if (a.equals(b)) return;
    }
    this.autor[cont++] = a;
}
```

Além disso, há muita coisa confusa no seu código, como `Pessoa` ser um conjunto de autores, ou `getAutor` devolver um array (não deveria ser `getAutores` então?). Seu método `equals`, aliás, é supérfluo, visto que o `equals` genérico já faria o que você quer.

Comment: Eu criei as classes apenas para estudo.

Comment: Boas práticas são cabíveis sempre :)

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira utilizar uma estrutura que não permite objetos duplicados talvez seja bom dar uma olhada no `Set`. Caso queira utilizar o array, mas também se aproveitar deste recurso do `Set`, implemente o método `hashCode` da sua classe `Autor`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.nome.hashCode();
}
```

E então utilize a conversão:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Autor[] autores = new Autor[3];

  autores[0] = new Autor("Leonardo");
  autores[1] = new Autor("Leonardo");
  autores[2] = new Autor("Joao");

  Set<Autor> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(autores));
  autores = set.toArray(new Autor[set.size()]);
}
```